# Momentary loss of RAID makes Windows 7 lose user accounts stored therein

Tags: windows-7, bios, raid, user-accounts

I have a AMD Phenom x3 chip in a ASUS M4A89GTD PRO motherboard.  The Mobo's bios lets me select 3 cores or 4 cores among 8 stored profiles.  I recently set the profile (I call **200NoHybridSSD**) to operate 4 cores with a 'Users' directory set to operate in a RAID1 set of drives.  Basically, the Mobo sets the drives to RAID1 when I use the correct bios configuration.

I tried booting an alternate bios profile that has these drives in IDE.  Needless to say, the Windows-7 failed to recognize the 'Users' folders and the 'Users' profiles that were established to the RAID (F:\users).  Basically, I had 2 Admin accounts (one called 'admin' and another called 'madmin') and 2 non-Admin user accounts, where the former were based in the boot drive, and the latter in RAIDed F:\Users.

So, after discovering that the machine couldn't locate the F:\Users based accounts on boot, I reverted to the **200NoHybridSSD** bios profile that does start the f:\Users drives in RAID.  However, now, instead of being presented with four icons/user-accounts to login with, I'm presented a single admin account, and an 'other' account.  Once I login, I can see each of the four user's directories (two non-admins in f:\users).  So all the data is intact.  What I'm guessing, is that the *registry* was changed when I booted into the non-RAIDed configuration.  I can still login to the both **admin** accounts (provided I type the account name -- icon is not always there).  My question: Can I recover or restore the non-admin accounts so they can be logged-in at the initial login screen?  Note, I have turned off the 'System Restore' function.

I haven't tried to yet, but I may build additional new user accounts to f:\Users (and be extra careful switching profiles in the future).  Will my previous 'disappearance' of f:\Users impact future creations of user accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your registry was changed. I saw a similar thing happen with changing domains on a Windows 7 machine.

I would recommend recreating the users in Control Panel (make a full backup first), and as long as the user folder is still there, it should remember everything.

EDIT:

An addendum: I've always found it wise to rename the old user folder first before creating the new account, then logging in, just to ensure the folder name is correct. Then I'll *move* the previous files back into the new folder (including hidden and system) from an Admin account, and you should be ok.